# Superset does not show S3 link to download Athena results

Tags: amazon-athena, apache-superset

We are using Athena in our data warehouse which is connected to the superset BI tool. Sometimes the query results are really large and superset cannot display the result. What we need is to get the S3 link in superset so that for huge queries, users can download this data directly from S3 in case Superset cannot show such a large result set

How can this be possible?